# PyQt: How can I access the attributes in a class method from another file

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

```
A.py

from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(203, 146)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
    
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.open_other_window)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(Form.close)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Enter"))

    def open_other_window(self):
        import B

        self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.ui = B.Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

What I simply want to do is simply access the attributes of `A.py` like `self.lineEdit` because I want to set the text of `B.self.label` to whatever the user inputs in `A.self.lineEdit`.

```
B.py

from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setText("Default Text")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Here are the things that I've done so far:

```
B.py
    def change_text(self):
        import A

        win = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        obj = A.Ui_Form()
        obj.setupUi(win)

        txt = obj.lineEdit.text()
        self.label.setText(txt)
```

And:

```
A.py

win = QtWidgets.QWidget()
obj = Ui_Form()
obj.setupUi(win)

input_txt = obj.lineEdit.text()

B.py 

    def change_text(self):
        import A

        
        txt = A.input_txt
        self.label.setText(txt)
```

Both show the same result, when I hit the `A` button, it redirects me to `B`. But then the text isn't even changed to `A.self.lineEdit` text, however the default text written "Default text" disappears.

Comment: The "simple" solution would be to do `self.ui.label.setText(self.lineEdit.text())` after calling `self.ui.setupUi(self.window)`. The reality is that you're **not** supposed to edit pyuic generated files, but only use them ***as they are*** as imports in files that will contain the actual "main script" of your program, which would implement subclasses as explained in the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). With that, you could also add further arguments to the `__init__` of those subclasses, which you can use to pass values.

Comment: Thank you so much, I haven't really thought about changing the text from another file, I was more focused on importing the attribute and changing the text in its own file. I appreciate your advice about editing a pyuic generated file, I will read more documentation about that.